# Can't access router's web interface

Tags: networking, router, troubleshooting

I had this problem for a while, however it only became really annoying recently as I needed to forward a few ports.

My problem: **I can't access the web interface of my router when typing 192.168.1.1 into a browser.**

I tried rebooting the router, using a different browser, using a different computer, checking firewall and probably some other stuff that I don't remember since this is going on for a few years.

Yes, the router address is correct and yes, I'm in the same subnet.

No, there doesn't seem to be any other device with the same IP.

What's really puzzling me right now is that I remember being able to access it through telnet when the issues first started, however the connection is timing out now.

The only option that I have left seems to be factory resetting the router, however I do not want to risk losing TV in addition to the internet if I somehow won't be able to set it back up.

Comment: if with the help of your ISP And router manufacturer you can't set it back up then i'm sure that one or the other will tell you it's faulty! also do you have the router and modem separate? You might still be able to watch TV connecting it directly with no NAT. And some people risk accessing the internet like that - with a software firewall eg the win7 firewall though if connecting directly just modem no NAT then i'd suggest testing your security, with a port scan with eg grc.com's shields up.

Comment: No, it's a router with directly connected DSL line. It doesn't seem to be faulty, the only thing not working is the web interface. I'm trying to avoid any possible downtime, that's why I want to avoid the factory reset.

Comment: ok it's a router-dsl modem device. What is the make/model of it? maybe you can backup the current configuration.  Why are you talking about losing TV when your router-dsl modem device, is down. if it's a router-dsl modem. As far as I know, DSL doesn't carry TV.  Cable does.

Comment: We have IPTV. It's a DrayTek Vigor model, 2700 I think.

Comment: The DrayTek vigor range uses HTTPS and port 10443 to access the admin pages. I.e. https://192.168.1.1:10443

Comment: @BigChris it's years old router, the firmware was never updated and it always worked by just using 192.168.1.1. I tried your suggestion though, but it didn't help

Comment: I should also add that it always fails with "The server is taking too long to respond" error, not a "server not found" one.

Comment: What's your `ipconfig /all` for your LAN card?

Comment: @BigChris http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KLkB7vmX - Sorry about the language, it still infuriates me that Microsoft won't let Home version users change the system language.

Comment: All seems ok. Can you ping 192.168.1.1? Try doing an `ipconfig /release` then `ipconfig /renew` then `ipconfig /flushdns`. If still not working open an elevated cmd and type `netsh winsock reset` then restart computer.

Comment: Are you trying to connect through wifi? If so, have you tried through a wired port instead?

Comment: not sure how long this will take but `C:\blah>nmap -P0 -p1-65535 192.168.1.1`  If you can ping it then remove the -P0. That will show you what ports, if any, are open.

Answer (score -1):

Try just factory resetting. The IPTV may autoconfigure itself after it resets. If not, just contact your provider.

Comment: no it will not. PPP in the router-modem   has to log onto the isp with a user/pass

Comment: A lot of times that's built in to the device.

Comment: I doubt that very much(unless you don't reset it properly and don't do a factory reset successfully so equivalent to just turning off and on most devices will retain info from last time. But not by automation and not after a factory reset). Provide a  Source if you are making this claim

Comment: Personal experience, however I may have only done a settings reset not a full reset. I have added to my answer.

Comment: if such a feature existed it'd have a name even a protocol(a source might then be a wikipedia article on that feature or a mention of it in the manual of that router/modem). it'd also have people baffled saying that a factory reset isn't resetting details on the router.    what model of router do you think this may be true of?  i'm sure you just turned it off and on and didn't do a factory reset.

Comment: I don't remember, it was a few years ago. I know I did some sort of reset because setting values got changed, but it must not have been a full reset.

Comment: did it autoconfigure when you bought it / first plugged it in?

Comment: No it won't autoconfigure. You have to enter the PPP user/pass. There's no problem with that, I'm however worried about the IPTV, no idea if it requires any additional config on the router.

Comment: Did it require any other config when you first set it up?

Comment: I really don't know, it was ages ago.

Comment: What brand IPTV?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by brand, but the provider is Telekom (Slovakia)